# how do I do big int multiplication using linked lists in C?

Tags: c, linked-list, multiplication, bigint

I am taking the input in string format. Then I am converting each digit to an integer, and storing each digit in a linked list node. I could have used arrays, but avoided that because they have a memory limit and are static.
Please tell me where I am going wrong in the following code?

```
# include<stdio.h>
# include<stdlib.h>
# include<string.h>

  struct ll{
    int digit;
    int place;
    struct ll *next;
  };


  typedef struct ll node;
    node *insert(node *head,int dig, int plac)//to insert new nodes{
         if(head==NULL){
            head=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
            head->digit=dig;
            head->place=plac;
            head->next=NULL;
            return head;
        }
        else{   
            head->next=insert(head->next,dig,plac);
            return head;
        }   
    }

    void print(node *a)//to print all the nodes in the linked list{
        node *temp;
        temp=a;
        while(temp!=NULL){
            printf("%d\n",temp->digit);
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }

    node *string_to_trainofdig(char h[],node *head){                     //converting a string to integer digits and storing them individually in the linked list

        int q,i;
        q=strlen(h);int j;node *temp;temp=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        printf("value of q is %d\n",q);
        for(i=q-1;i>=0;i--){
            printf("value of i %d\n",i);
            switch(h[i]){       
                case '0':j=0;break;
                case '1':j=1;break;
                case '2':j=2;break;
                case '3':j=3;break;
                case '4':j=4;break;
                case '5':j=5;break;
                case '6':j=6;break;
                case '7':j=7;break;
                case '8':j=8;break;
                case '9':j=9;break; 

            }
            printf("j is %d\n",j);
            temp=insert(head,j,i);
            head=temp;
        }
        return temp;
    }



    int count(node *q){                          //counting the total number of nodes in a linked list
        int p=0;;
        node *w;
        w=q;

        while(w!=NULL){
            p++;
            w=w->next;              
        }
        return p;   
    }


    int pos(node *a, int y){                  //this function returns the digit stored in a   //particular node (specified by its position) 
        y--;
        node *temp; temp=a;
        if(a==NULL){
            return 0;
        }
        else{   
            while(temp!=NULL || y!=0){
                temp=temp->next;
                    y--;
            }
            if(temp==NULL){
                return 0;
            }
            else if(y==0){
                return temp->digit;             
            }
        }       
    }

    node *modify(node *a,int value,int posi){   /*inserts nodes and assigns them     //values if empty (NULL) but modifies the value stored in that position in the //linked list if not NULL*/
        node *temp; temp=a; posi--;
        if(a==NULL){
            return insert(a,value,posi);
        }
        else{   
            while(temp!=NULL || posi!=0){
                temp=temp->next;
                posi--;
            }
            if(temp==NULL){
                return NULL;
            }
            else if(posi==0){
              temp->digit=value;
            }
            return a;
        }
    }

    char *mult(node *a,node *b){               //taking two linked lists as parameters and  multiplying them 

        char e[1000000];
        node *as; node *bs;
        as=a;bs=b; 
        int z,x,m,n,v,r;

        m=0; n=0;
        node *newe;node *newe2;
        char er[1000000];
        newe=NULL;

        int s;
        s=count(a)>count(b)?count(a):count(b);
        as=count(a)>count(b)?a:b;//determines which linked list is bigger and     //assigns that to as
        bs=count(a)>count(b)?b:a;//bs is smaller of the two linkedc lists

        int fr=0;int ca=0;  int i=0;

        while(bs!=NULL)//main algorithm{
            i=fr;//fr is initially 0
            while(as!=NULL){
                m=as->digit*bs->digit+m;//m is zero initially
                n=m%10;
                m=m/10;
                ca=(pos(newe,i));// ca gets the value stored in the ith position of node  //newe---->will be 0 initially since NULL 
                newe=modify(newe,n+ca,i);
                as=as->next;i++;        
            }
            as=count(a)>count(b)?a:b;
            bs=bs->next;    
            fr++;//increments fr so that i comes back to fr
        }
    }


    main(){
        char d[1000]; char p[1000];
        scanf("%s",d);
        scanf("%s",p);
        int q,w;

        node *l,*u; l=NULL; u=NULL;
        l=string_to_trainofdig(d,l);
        u=string_to_trainofdig(p,u);

        print(l);
        print(u);   

        char *t;
        t=mult(l,u);
        printf("done\n");

    }
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Consider using a real bigint library like [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/) since bigint arithmetic has clever efficient algorithms (better than the naive ones you could easily code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linked lists (especially for this case) give extremely poor performance. Every time you follow a link (e.g. `temp=temp->next;`) it's a potential cache miss, and destroys instruction parallelism on modern (out-of-order) CPUs because the new value of `temp` that subsequent code depends on can't be known until afterwards. They also tend to spread data everywhere (poor cache locality), which makes the first 2 problems worse, and makes linear iteration "un-prefetchable" (unlike "for each element in array" where CPU can trivially detect the pattern and prefetch the data before it's needed).

For big integers, storing integers as "base 10" also gives extremely poor performance. This is only slightly caused by less efficient memory usage (e.g. storing a value from 0 to 9 in each byte that could've stored a value from 0 to 255 instead). The main problem is that most higher level operations have either "per digit" overhead (addition, subtraction, AND, OR) or "per digit squared" overhead (multiplication). Small bases (e.g. "base 10") means more digits, which means a massive amount of overhead. Larger bases (e.g. "base 4294967296") means far fewer digits and lot less overhead. In addition to that using "power of 2" sizes allows you to use shifting and masking instead of modulus and division (e.g. `digit = temp%10; temp /= 10;` vs. `digit = temp & 0xFF; temp >>= 8;`); and using "whole integer" sizes makes it even more efficient (`digit = temp; temp >>= 32;`). Basically; to get acceptable performance you want to match the CPU's native size - e.g. use "base 4294967296" on 32-bit systems, and "base 18446744073709551616" on 64-bit systems.

If you combine both of these you might end up with something more like:

```
    typedef struct {
        int current_digits;
        int allocated_digits;
        uint32_t digits[];
    } BIG_INTEGER;
```

Note that the `current_digits` and `allocated_digits` fields let you avoid resizing the array all the time. For example:

```
#define EXTRA_DIGITS    16

    if(number->current_digits + 1 < number->allocated_digits) {
        number->allocated_digits = number->current_digits + 1 + EXTRA_DIGITS;
        newsize = sizeof(BIG_INTEGER) + sizeof(uint32_t)*number->allocated_digits;
        number = realloc(number, newsize);
    }
    number->digits[number->current_digits] = 0;
    number->current_digits++;
```

For multiplication itself; it would be roughly like this (assuming 32-bit or `uint32_t` is used for digits, not tested at all):

```
    uint64_t temp;             // Must be double the size of a digit

    for(i = 0; i < number1->current_digits; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < number2->current_digits; j++) {
            temp = number1->digits[i] * number2->digits[j];
            k = i+j;
            while(temp != 0) {
                temp = temp + result->digits[k];
                result->digits[k] = temp;    // Lower half only
                temp = temp >> 32;
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
```

You can probably convert this to work with linked lists instead of arrays; but...

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do integer maths with arbitrarily long integers then I would suggest using the [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) library or similar instead of doing it yourself.

> I could have used arrays, but avoided that because they have a memory limit and are static

This is not correct.  While you can declare an array as a static block in C, you can easily simply declare a pointer and malloc() space for that as you need it ( remembering to free() of course ).

> Please tell me where I am going wrong in the following code?

When posting questions that sort of vagueness is not the way to ask.

You tell *us* what is happening and what you expect, some sample input and output or error report.